# How to write soapui - Teststep level custom property values in file?

Tags: soap, groovy, properties, soapui

I am very new to SoapUI, and need some help,
I want to test multiple SOAP requests - just kind of smoke test and save result in text file along with error message of failed response.

I have created testcase with all SOAP request and used invalid HTTP assertion to validate pass/fail one [as mentioned just smoke test] and wirting result in to txt file using tear down script.

I have created Custom properties for each SOAP request and using property transfer step fetched Error message & reporting entity.

Now my concern is, how to write those property values in txt file along with result.

I am using below mentioned teardown script to store result.

```
`import org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.*
 import org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.tlb.office.excel.*

 def testsuitename=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.name
 def testcasename=testRunner.testCase.name
 groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
 def results = testRunner.results
 f = new File( "C:\\Users\\%user%\\Documents\\Downloads\\Smoke Test Result\\result.txt")

 for( r in testRunner.results )
 {
    f.append(r.testStep.name + "," + r.status + "\r\n")

 }`
```

Output is something like this:

```
step-1-name,FAILED
step-2-name,OK
step-3-name,OK
```

I am looking for output with error message

```
step-1-name,FAILED,Error message,Reporting Entity
step-2-name,OK,null,null
step-3-name,OK,null,null
```

I have already fetched Error message & entity using XPATH in properties.

Comment: I believe that the approach is not right. You can use testrunner script of SOAPUI_HOME/bin to tests and it creates those automatically. You do not even required to open soapui.

Comment: "I am very new to SoapUI, and need some help..." Perhaps spending some time with the documentation would help?

Comment: @Rao, May b you didn't get my question. I want to get the out put in above mentioned format,and just FYI I m running testcase using testrunner only. If you are suggesting to use those report, then it will be ev3n difficult as testrunner export xml of failed testcases.